# Class modeling: Inheritance with Generics: Kotlin / Java

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, inheritance, model

I am trying to model a tournament project having the following classes:

- **Championship** -> having a list of Divisions.
- **Division** -> having a list of Leagues.
- **League** -> having a list of LeagueMembers;
- **LeagueMember** -> is abstract because **Player** and **Team** extend it (a league can be made by a list of players or a list of teams)

The thing is that I'd like to be able to create a TennisLeague, extending League<Player>, and FootballLeague, extending League<Team>. The problem is that I am trying to use Generics but it seems like I have to use them in all the clases, and it looks weird to me.

Am I following the right approach? Could you help me with the class modeling? Thanks

Comment: You'd use generics in the case that you have a need for the concrete subtypes (e.g. when you want something more specific than `Object` out of `List`). Ideally, you would model these classes in a way that you can simply keep a reference to `League` (with appropriate methods like `League#getMembers()`), and then pass concrete classes like `TennisLeague` in place of whatever `League` is required

Comment: but, the method getMembers should return a list of Player for TennisLeague and a list of Team for other classes.. Then I'd need generics, wouldn't I?

Comment: You can simply return a `List<? extends LeagueMember>` in that case, and the subclasses are free to return `List<Player>` or somesuch.